# How to recover table after drop it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore, recovery

I drop a table in SQL Server using this code:

```
DROP TABLE temp
```

Now, I try to recover this table, but I don't know a solution.

Please, tell me a solution for this problem if you know.

Comment: Short of a backup, you might be in trouble. But you could try to roll back the tansaction:BEGIN TRAN DROP TABLE temp ROLLBACK SELECT * FROM temp

Comment: if you have the transaction logs you can TRY to reconstruct it

Comment: The basic question is: which recovery model is the database in: simple or full? :)

Comment: full model of table :)

Comment: If recovery model is really full, it is possible to take a log backup and then restore to another server with stop at option. I suggest you find someone on premise to help you with this if you don't have experience with SQL Server backup and restore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If DROP TABLE was executed inside the Transaction and it has not been committed then you can ROLLBACK. But if it isn't, then you need backup of your database. Recover your table from database. If backup is also not present, then search for 3rd party recovery tools.

Comment: i don't use TRANSACTION and don't have database backup :(.
so 3th party tools, you can show me some tools ???